# Electron contextBridge returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, electron, ipc

I've got these 4 project files:

```
main.js
preload.js
renderer.js
index.html
```

Node: 17.4.0
Electron: 18.2.0

I'm attempting to open a text file on my filesystem, triggered by a click event from **renderer.js** - then load the text file's contents into a `<div>` tag in index.html.

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const createWindow = () => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
         webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: true,
            nodeIntegration: false
         }
    });
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));

    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

app.on("ready", () => {
    createWindow();

    app.on("activate", () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
    });
});


function openFile(){
    fs.readFile("logs.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return "Error Loading Log File";
        }
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
}

ipcMain.handle("channel-load-file", openFile);
```

**preload.js**

```
const {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
    loadFile: () => ipcRenderer.invoke("channel-load-file")
});
```

**renderer.js**

```
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
   let data = window.electronAPI.loadFile();
   document.getElementById("main-content").innerText = data;
});
```

I can definitely see the contents of the Log file inside `console.log(data);` in the **main.js**

But, the `<div id="main-content"></div>` gets populated with **undefined**.

I believe I'm missing some crucial step within either: `preload.js` or `renderer.js`

Anyone see where the chain of events is getting lost?

(I'm very open to any improvements to my flow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting `console.log()`'s in the code below indicates that the `handle` content is executed before `openFile` has
a chance to return a result.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
function openFile() {
    fs.readFile("logs.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return "Error Loading Log File";
        }

        console.log('openFile: ' + data); // Testing

        return data;
    });
}

ipcMain.handle('channel-load-file', () => {
    let result = openFile();

    console.log('handle: ' + result); // Testing

    return result;
})
```

The `console.log()` results are...

```js
handle: undefined
openFile: File content...
```

---

To fix this, let's change `fs.readFile` from a callback to a promise, so we can `await` for it in the `handle`.

As the `handle` is dealing with a promise, let's use the syntactic sugar `async` and `await` for easier implementation.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
function openFile() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile("logs.txt", "utf-8", (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('reject: ' + error); // Testing
                reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log('resolve: ' + data); // Testing
                resolve(data)
            }
        });
    });
}

ipcMain.handle('channel-load-file', async (event, message) => {
    return await openFile()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('handle: ' + data); // Testing
            return data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('handle error: ' + error); // Testing
            return 'Error Loading Log File';
        })
});
```

Lastly, let's modify the way we retrieve the `data` in the `index.html` file.

PS: Let's also add `.toString()` to the returned `data` (just to be sure).

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main-content"></div>

        <input type="button" id="button" value="Load File">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.electronAPI.loadFile()
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data); // Testing
                    document.getElementById("main-content").innerText = data.toString();
                });
        })
    </script>
</html>
```